# Split mathematical expression on every operator/bracket

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to split math expressions using regex although no matter what I try, there's always one condition that I'm missing.
I need to split the string on all operators `+,-,*,/` and on all types of brackets `(,),[,]`. If there's an increment or decrement `++,--` I need to keep it as one string. I also have to keep multidigit numbers as one string.

Right now, the closest thing I have is:
`(?<![+-[0-9]])(?=[*/+-\[\]\(\)])|(?<=[*/+-\[\]\(\)])(?![+-[0-9]])`

For example, `[(([++[[(--2)]*33]])/22)+1]` should give
`[,(,(,[,++,[,[,(,--,2,),],*,33,],],),/,22,),+,1,]` but instead gives
`[,(,(,[,++,[,[,(,`**--2**`,),],*,33,],],),/,22,),`**+1**`,]`

Comment: I wouldn't use a regex for this. Should be much easier (and more performant) using a normal loop.

Comment: @marstran Mmm always thought a loop would be slower. I'd still like to understand how I could make it work using regex though

Comment: Refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 2):

tldr: **Other developers that inherit your code will be able to understand the `\d+` regex... But they're very unlikely to be able to look at your monster of a regex — or any other long regex, for that matter — and understand what's going on.**

If there's a simpler way to do it without regexes, that's usually the better option for both readability and performance. But if you *must* use regex...

My recommendation is to use the much simpler `\d+` to find all digits, or `\D` to find all non-digits; then, you should loop through the result and combine any subsets of the array `tokens` where `tokens[i]` and `tokens[i+1]` are both `+` or `-`.

As commenters have noted, this is still likely less performant than ignoring RegExes altogether and splitting using a loop.

While regular expressions are interesting and very useful for certain tasks, matching-bracket tasks like this is *particularly* poorly suited for regex (because the math syntax we commonly use is [not a regular language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)).